# How to get the centre of the view

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to get the center of my view by using the code below, the class being used is from the `DTIActivityIndicatorView` which add a custom activity indicator to the view.

```
var midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)
var midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)

let topStoriesActivityIndicator: DTIActivityIndicatorView = DTIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: midX, y: midY, width:80.0, height:80.0))
```

But the code above is giving me the following result where the activity indicator isn't centered in the middle.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Swift 4 extension:**

```
extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint { .init(x: midX, y: midY) }
}

let someRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 40)

let theCenter = someRect.center // {x 110 y 30}
```

Comment: What do you mean by someRect? can you give some examples of this? Thanks

Comment: Added someRect. Br.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3**

The following code represent the center of Screen:

```
let frameSize: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*0.5,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*0.5)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX and UIScreen.main.bounds.midY also works in swift 4

Comment: Note that UIScreen.main is not a `view` center, it's whole screen `center`.

Answer (score 11):

Bounds can be different than how size of the view appears. Try using frame and if it doesn't work try using bounds.

```
var midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)
var midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)
```

Also since you are positioning your view in the center and then adding width and height, it appears off as well. You should set the frame like this

```
let topStoriesActivityIndicator: DTIActivityIndicatorView = DTIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: midX - 80.0, y: midY - 80.0, width:80.0, height:80.0))
```

Comment: Done that and it produces the exact same results

Comment: `bounds` is the correct property to be using here; getting the MidX/Y of the frame will produce the wrong result if the frame’s origin is non-zero.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3:**

```
let someRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
let midX = someRect.midX
let midY = someRect.midY
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :-

```
var midY = self.view.frame.height / 2
var midX = self.view.frame.width / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
let frameSize: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:self.view.bounds.midX, y:self.view.bounds.midY)

let frameSize: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:yourView.bounds.midX, y:yourView.bounds.midY)
```

Or

```
 let frameSize: CGPoint = self.view.center
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let width = 80
let height = 80
```

let

```
topStoriesActivityIndicator: DTIActivityIndicatorView = DTIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - ( width * 0.5), y: view.bounds.midY - ( height * 0.5) , width: width, height: height))
```

This may be able to help resolve the problem