# Error: Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'center'

Tags: swift

Trying to create layout for a circular collection view. Everything seems well apart from when I try to center the position.

```
override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        itemLayoutAttributes.removeAll()
        layoutCircleFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: collectionViewContentSize)
            .inset(by: layoutInsets)
            .insetBy(dx: itemSize.width / 2.0, dy: itemSize.height / 2.0)
            .offsetBy(dx: collectionView.contentOffset.x, dy: collectionView.contentOffset.y)
            .insetBy(dx: -collectionView.contentOffset.x, dy: -collectionView.contentOffset.y)

        for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
            switch section {
            case 0:
                let itemCount = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
                itemLayoutAttributes = (0..<itemCount).map({ (index) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in
                    let angleStep: CGFloat = 2.0 * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(itemCount)
                    var position = layoutCircleFrame.center
                    position.x += layoutCircleFrame.size.innerRadius * cos(angleStep * CGFloat(index))
                    position.y += layoutCircleFrame.size.innerRadius * sin(angleStep * CGFloat(index))
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: section)
                    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                    attributes.frame = CGRect(center: position, size: itemSize)
                    return attributes
                })
            default:
                fatalError("Unhandled section \(section).")
            }
        }
```

Expected to run but instead receive the error: Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'center'. This error is on the line;

```
var position = layoutCircleFrame.center
```

Comment: Perhaps that code relies on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152021 (or a similar) extension?

Comment: That code seems to be copied from https://augmentedcode.io/2019/01/20/circle-shaped-collection-view-layout-on-ios/. If you download the sample project from that site then you'll find an extension method for the center property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is add this extension to my code (at the top level of a file):

```
extension CGRect {
    var center : CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x:self.midX, y:self.midY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `center` property in `CGRect`, hence the error. It's a property of `UIView`.

You could do:

```
var position = CGPoint(x: layoutCircleFrame.midX, y: layoutCircleFrame.midY)
```

Or, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152021), you can add a `center` property to `CGRect` via an extension.